# Change background-size on button?

Tags: css

I have a larger image, but I want to control the background size using CSS to get it down to 48x78px. How can I do this?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe0bs805/) of the below:

```css
.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  background-size: 48px 78px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/YiHjEd1.png") no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0px;
  height: 78px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 48px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" style="display: block;">Previous</button>
```

Comment: Place the `background-size` *after* the `background: url();` [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7nvq9cfq/)

Comment: @misterManSam perfect, if you put down an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background` property allows you to specify background properties in shorthand, including the `background-size` property. Currently your `background-size` is being overwritten with the default `auto`.

### Two Methods

1. Place the `background-size` *after* the `background` property:

   ```
   background: url("http://i.imgur.com/YiHjEd1.png") no-repeat;
   background-size: 48px 78px;
   ```

   This overwrites the default `auto` value given by the `background` property.

   #### Example

   ```css
   .slick-prev,
   .slick-next {
     background: url("http://i.imgur.com/YiHjEd1.png") no-repeat;
     background-size: 48px 78px;
     border: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 0px;
     height: 78px;
     line-height: 0px;
     margin-top: -10px;
     outline: none;
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     width: 48px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" style="display: block;">Previous</button>
   ```

**or**

2. Place the `background-size` values in the `background` property itself:

   ```
   background: url("http://i.imgur.com/YiHjEd1.png") 0 / 48px 78px no-repeat;
   ```

   The `0` is the same as the default `background-position` value and needs to be specified. The `/` indicates that the following lengths are for the `background-size`. This is nicely explained [over here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background#Syntax).

   #### Example

   ```css
   .slick-prev,
   .slick-next {
     background: url("http://i.imgur.com/YiHjEd1.png") 0 / 48px 78px no-repeat;
     border: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 0px;
     height: 78px;
     line-height: 0px;
     margin-top: -10px;
     outline: none;
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     width: 48px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" style="display: block;">Previous</button>
   ```